# Update each row of one table with multiple row data from other table using join condition in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
  DECLARE @outerCounter INT = 1, @rowCount INT,
@query NVARCHAR(MAX), @load numeric(18,3), @batcolno NVARCHAR(MAX), @inCounter INT = 1,@innerrowsCount INT
SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(*) FROM tempA

WHILE(@outercounter <= @rowCount)
BEGIN

    SELECT @innerrowsCount = COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
    tempB INNER JOIN tempA 
    ON  tempB.batteryid = tempA.batteryid
    AND 
    tempB.uniquerowid = @outercounter 

    WHILE(@inCounter <= @innnerrowCounter)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @laod = laod FROM tempB INNER JOIN tempA 
        ON  tempB.batteryid = tempA.batteryid 
        AND 
        tempB.uniquerowid = @inCounter

        SET @testcolno = 'batt' + REPLACE(STR(@inCounter,3),' ','0')

         SET @query = ' UPDATE tempA
                    SET '+ @testcolno + ' = '+ @load +'
                    WHERE tempA.rowid = '+ @outercounter + '    '       
        EXEC(@query)
        SET @inCounter = @inCounter + 1         
    END
    SET @outercounter = @outercounter + 1
END
```

I have 2 tables tempA and tempB.

tempA:

```
batteryid | batname |  batt01 | batt02 |  batt03 | batt04
----------+---------+---------+--------+---------+--------
01        | trixon  |  null   | null   |  null   | null
03        | jaguarv |  null   | null   |  null   | null
```

tempB:

```
batteryid  |  load
-----------+---------
01         |  14.58
01         |  58.12
01         |  16.89
03         |  25.47
03         |  87.65
```

Final output in tempA should be like this:

```
batteryid | batname  | batt01   | batt02 | batt03  | batt04
----------|----------|----------|--------|---------|--------------
01        | trixon   |    14.58 | 58.12  | 16.89   | null
03        | jaguarv  |    25.47 | 87.65  | null    | null
```

Above code uses while loop to update the tempA table by joining batteryid with that of tempB table.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I used while loop to loop through the tempB table and fetch the matching batterids and update the column value of tempB in first table columns like batt01. While loop takes longer time to execute 15000 records.

Comment: Show us the code and we will start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with using a `PIVOT` in SQL Server, and you'll be able to do away with the loop and update statements.

```
SELECT  SourceA.[batteryid], 
        SourceA.[batname],
        SourcePivot.[1] AS 'Battery1',
        SourcePivot.[2] AS 'Battery2',
        SourcePivot.[3] AS 'Battery3',
        SourcePivot.[4] AS 'Battery4'
FROM @tempA AS SourceA
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM
        (
          SELECT batteryId, 
                 loadval,
                 row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY batteryid ORDER BY loadval) rn
          FROM @tempB
        ) s
        PIVOT (MIN(loadval) FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) pvt
    ) AS SourcePivot ON SourcePivot.batteryid = SourceA.batteryid
```

Here is the code that I used to test the query

```
DECLARE @tempA TABLE (
    batteryid VARCHAR(2),
    batname VARCHAR(50), 
    batt01 DECIMAL(18, 2),
    batt02 DECIMAL(18, 2),
    batt03 DECIMAL(18, 2),
    batt04 DECIMAL(18, 2)
)

DECLARE @tempB TABLE (
    batteryid VARCHAR(2), 
    loadval DECIMAL(18, 2)
)

INSERT INTO @tempA (batteryid, batname) VALUES ('01', 'trixon')
INSERT INTO @tempA (batteryid, batname) VALUES ('03', 'jaguarv')
INSERT INTO @tempB VALUES ('01', '14.58')
INSERT INTO @tempB VALUES ('01', '58.12')
INSERT INTO @tempB VALUES ('01', '16.89')
INSERT INTO @tempB VALUES ('03', '25.47')
INSERT INTO @tempB VALUES ('03', '87.65')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @kane. I have one problem columns in tempA like batt01,batt02,batt03 are not fixed they vary depends on the count and are added in the tempA table. for ex: if count is 30 then 30 columns are added and i have to do the same updation for 30 columns dynamically.